# Acer Travelmate P645-MG Windows 8.1 display sleep issues

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, sleep

I have an Acer Travelmate P645-MG, it comes with Windows 8 that I downgraded to Windows 7 64bit and all is well there.

I would love to run Windows 8.1 64 bit as it addresses a lot of my gripes over windows 8 but I am running into driver issues.

This computer has the Intel HD4400 graphics and AMD 8750M(2gb) graphics cards.

I installed all of the Windows 8.1 64 bit drivers from Acer's support site specific to this computer and they all install well with no errors or gripes upon installation. Upon restarting, everything seems perfectly fine except I cannot get the AMD Catalyst software to load, it says there are no configurable settings (from what I read, the AMD driver installed is not being detected by AMD software) although in device manager and opening a well-known game does have access to the AMD GPU and runs very well.

Being without the ability to access the AMD catalyst controls is a bummer not being able to set what applications have access to the AMD graphics such as Adobe Premiere, etc.

I then uninstalled both Intel and AMD graphics drivers entirely, reinstalled the intel driver and installed AMD's latest drivers from AMD. The computer would NOT sleep or hibernate. **I then tried the beta drivers which states that it addresses these issues, the two latest Beta drivers DO work and the AMD catalyst control panel shows up and functions! Great! It sleeps, hibernates, wakes up, etc**. **But here's the last issue:** If I am on battery power and the screen goes to sleep (not the computer) after 5 seconds or so I try to wake it up and it WILL not turn the screen back on (power lights on, hdd activity still blinks) and have to force shut down. I've been trying to address this over and over with no results by changing power options, reinstalling drivers, etc etc... Anyone know the magical answer?

I even tried installing HP's AMD driver packages as I have read other laptops with identical graphics setups had this issue as well in Windows 8.1 and apparently HP fixed this with their drivers. Their drivers install, they work, it sleeps, hibernates, wakes up, but the screen itself cannot fall sleep- it won't wake up.

**Acer had no answer.**

Thank you for reading!

Comment: This link explains what's the reason.https://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2990029/en-us

Answer (score 0):

I have the same machine and ran into the exact same problem after upgrading from Windows 8 to 8.1. I tried installing and uninstalling the drivers from the Acer website, and tried newer drivers from the AMD website, and always the same problem: if both AMD and Intel drivers are installed, the machine will not return from either sleep or hibernation.

In desperation, I reloaded Windows 8, which works perfectly.

Apparently people with Dell computers have found Dell versions of AMD and Intel drivers that solve the problem, but I haven't tried to see if they work on the Acer machine:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-hardware/driver-conflict-amd-radeon-8670m-on-windows-81/98eb93f3-ad78-4813-8e57-ee7d4504d770

Please let me know if loading these on the Acer P645-MG running Windows 8.1 works (need to install the Intel driver first apparently).